# how can I fix a closing tag problem in read me

Tags: git, github, repository

How do I fix this error on github :

The variable {{a} on line 50 in Natours/node_modules/balanced-match/README.md was not properly closed with }}.

Comment: Where/how do you see this error? What is the content of the README.md file at this location? Can you post a [mcve]?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. You are very welcome to ask questions here, but they would need to be more circumstanciated. How does this error occur ?

Comment: just add the second }:
{{a} ->> {{a}}

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I see the error on GitHub when trying to build my page. The README.md is in balanced match folder inside the node modules folder.

Comment: @LeGEC Thanks. This error occurs when I try to build my page on GitHub. It says I can build the page because of that error in my node modules folder